# How to loop through records to send single POST request to server?

Tags: sql-server, json, python-requests, pyodbc

I have a SQL table that I am  looping through to send a single post request to a server for each record.  All records should be separate JSONs.

I am expecting something like this:

```
while there are rows in table:
write the number of rows as json and output files.

while there are rows being written as jsons and output files:
server is pinged for the number of jsons and output files.
```

if `objects_list.append(d)` is in the loop and `fetchmany` change to `fetchall` all records are returned, as one json object, I would like to iterate through the table and have each record sent to the server as a single json in the structure below.   So iterating through the table and breaking the loop when all records have been written as a json object and sent to server with requests.

Sample JSON
`{
    "MetaData": {}, 
    "SRData": {
        "SRNumber": "1-3580671"
    }
}`

I am using Pyodbc to iterate my table and pull the records that I would like to send to the server.

My script returns the first record, I would like to loop through the table and return X amount of records within a certain time frame as defined by a where clause.

How do I successfully return each row as a single JSON that pings the server that it is being sent to?

Code:

```
import pyodbc
import json
import collections
import requests
import time
import logging
import httplib
import datetime
import logging
import logging.handlers


start = time.time()

connstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=ServiceRequest; UID=SA;PWD=pwd'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""SELECT SRNUMBER FROM MYLA311 """)
rows = cursor.fetchmany()



objects_list = []
for row in rows:
     d = collections.OrderedDict()
     d['SRNumber']= row.SRNUMBER



objects_list.append(d)

output = {"MetaData": {},
"SRData": d}

print output

j = json.dumps(output)
b =  json.dumps(output, sort_keys=True, indent=4)


objects_file = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\JSONOutput.txt'
f = open(objects_file,'w')

url = "https://myla311.lacity.org/myla311router/mylasrbe/1/UpsertSANSR"
headers = {'Content-type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': '/'}
r = requests.post(url, data= json.dumps(output), headers=headers,  verify=False)

print 'It took', time.time()-start, 'seconds.'

print r.text

conn.close()
```

Output:

```
{
    "MetaData": {}, 
    "SRData": {
        "SRNumber": "1-3140751"
    }
}
{"status":{"code":311,"message":"Service Request Successfully updated","cause":""},"Response":{"PrimaryRowId":"1-1VBF3","ListOfServiceRequest":{"ServiceRequest":[{"SRNumber":"1-3140751"}]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change `cursor.fetchmany()` to `cursor.fetchall()` ? Also what if you put `objects_list.append(d)` inside the for loop and set

```
 output = {"MetaData": {}, "SRData": objects_list}
```

Comment: nope, same output, I think it's a bit more complex than that, seems as if I need a while loop for my output that iterates each row in the table as a new JSON object and writes a new object file.

Comment: what if you put objects_list.append(d) inside the for loop?

Comment: No, I think you are thinking that I'd like to return all records from a table as a single JSON,  I would like to return all records from a table as single JSONs .

Comment: OK so i guess you want to pass objects_list to the output. You still need to put it inside the for loop though.

Comment: See edits, I'd like to iterate through the whole table and send each row as a JSON to the server and break the loop at the last record.